# Can't see string variable in filter menu

Tags: string, filter, spss

Context: I need to filter a column (string variable), namely I need to exclude all of the results in this column that contains `0,0%`. My main goal is to make a histogram with the results of this column but without `0,0%`.

Problem:
When I press select cases I do not see this variable in the dialog window. Because of that, I can not use `"use filter variable"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog doesn't show string variables. You can still filter of select through syntax:

```
select if YourVar <> "0,0%".
```